# Conversion Fahrenheit to celsius programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my project, want to show the weather in fahrenheit first, then if the user wants clickes on conversion, needs to show the weather in celsius. My code is

```
NSNumber *metric = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"metric"];

NSLog(@"Metric is %@", metric);

CGFloat aFloat = [speed floatValue];
CGFloat tFloat = [temperature floatValue];
CGFloat tempFloat = (tFloat-30)/2;
NSNumber * p_Number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:tempFloat];


//Convert mph to kmph
if ([metric boolValue]) {

    [windValueLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f kmph", aFloat * 1.6]  ];
    temperatureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", p_Number];

}
else{
    [windValueLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f mph", aFloat / 1.6]];
    temperatureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", temperature];
}
```

When u start the app, its working and showing temperature in fahrenheit, but crashes at celsius man... is that the current conversion. help me out guys

Comment: What error do you get? Check your console

Comment: That isn't your code as that converts between mph and km/h!

Comment: @trojanfoe did you try to read it ? The conversion goes for the second label. The formula is incorrect but is pretty close, it must be `C = 5/9 * (F-32)`

Comment: The error is signal aborting error

Comment: You will need to post the stacktrace to get any further...

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is slightly off, you want:

```
CGFloat tempFloat = (tFloat-32.0) / 1.8;
```

But that's not what making it crash.  In fact, it's not crashing for me.  What message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: That's not good enough, you also need to say which line of your code caused it.  If you can't do that, then you don't have very good debugging skills :-S.